# My css gradient doesn't stretch, it repeats

Tags: css, gradient

```
body{
padding:0;
margin:0;
font:normal 12px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#383634;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left top,
left bottom,
color-stop(0.18, rgb(74,12,107)),
color-stop(0.87, rgb(102,153,102))
);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4a0c6b 0%, #669966 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4a0c6b),         color-stop(100%,#669966)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4a0c6b 0%,#669966 100%); /*    Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4a0c6b 0%,#669966 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4a0c6b 0%,#669966 100%); /* IE10+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4a0c6b', endColorstr='#669966',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
background: linear-gradient(top, #4a0c6b 0%,#669966 100%); /* W3C */
```

It goes most of the way down, then repeats

Answer (score 59):

Your original code: http://jsfiddle.net/ecKR4/7/

**If you want the gradient to stretch the entire height of the page:**

```
html {
    min-height: 100%
}
```

With little content: http://jsfiddle.net/ecKR4/1/
With lots of content: http://jsfiddle.net/ecKR4/2/

**If you want the gradient to be fixed and as high as the viewport:**

```
html {
    height: 100%
}
body {
    background-attachment: fixed
}
```

With little content: http://jsfiddle.net/ecKR4/3/
With lots of content: http://jsfiddle.net/ecKR4/4/

**If you want the gradient to be as high as the viewport, and then the background colour:**

```
html {
    height: 100%
}
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #669966; /* ending colour of gradient */
}
```

With little content: http://jsfiddle.net/ecKR4/5/
With lots of content: http://jsfiddle.net/ecKR4/6/

Comment: +1 for the "min-height".  I had been using "height" and could not get it working on all browsers.  Thanks!

Comment: You are a gentlemen and a scholar. It seems weird that `html` would ever NOT be 100% by default.

Comment: This really helped me!  Wish I could upvote it more than once.