# How to not repeat a CSS background gradient

Tags: css, background, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm working in a wordpress web, and I have a problem with the background gradient that I have made.

The problem is after the end of the footer, the gradient start again. I don't know how to solve this.

The css code that I do is the next:

```
body {
            background: #FFFFFF; /* old browsers */
        /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(51,102,153,1) 0%, rgba(51,102,153,0) 50%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(51,102,153,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(51,102,153,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(51,102,153,1) 0%,rgba(51,102,153,0) 50%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(51,102,153,1) 0%,rgba(51,102,153,0) 50%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(51,102,153,1) 0%,rgba(51,102,153,0) 50%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(51,102,153,1) 0%,rgba(51,102,153,0) 50%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#336699', endColorstr='#00336699',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

}
```

And the result (screenshot) is:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat) CSS property:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Edit: There is a more complete/helpful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6970142/1024766) that provides a couple of different solutions.

Comment: I've pasted that in the first line, but It doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin: See my edit. I've included a link to an answer on a similar question.

Comment: Sorry, It seems to work. Cache problem? Now work after clear the page cache.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this**

background-repeat: repeat-x;

Answer (score 0):

If the background image isn't full width and you want the gradient across, follow the the example below.

```
background-repeat:repeat-x; /* Repeats vertically across the scree */
```

**Note:** The above will never repeat horizontally and no matter the width of the screen, your gradient will still show across.
If you use no-repeat, it won't repeat but you'll have an issue if the background-image isn't full width. You gradient might not cover the width of your website.

**See more repeat options below:**

```
background-repeat:repeat-y; /* Repeats horizontally from top to bottom */

background-repeat: repeat; /* Repeats to cover every available space */

background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Doesn't repeat at all */
```