# Gradient Background Repeating

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have some trouble with a website I'm making for a school project. I have a gradient background but it repeats vertically, it is especially noticeable when you zoom out. Here's a photo:
[repeating background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALf5E.png)

Here's the code for the css (I'm guessing this is where the problem originates):

```css
html {
 background: #45aa99; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #10aaff 0%, #2288aa 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,10aaff), color-
                                         stop(100%,#2288aa)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #10aaff 0%,#2288aa 100%);  
                  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #10aaff 0%,#2288aa 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #10aaff 0%,#2288aa 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #10aaff 0%,#2288aa 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#10aaff', 
                 endColorstr='#2288aa',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 }
```

---

I would like the webpage to gradient for the entire length of the site no matter the zoom. Any idea how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Ps here's the pastebins to the full html and css:
html: [link](http://pastebin.com/mqBnUhv9)
css: [link](http://pastebin.com/2wS10X4K)

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

you can also specify the width and height of the background as follows:

```
background-size:100px 100px; /* width & height */
```

Here is a [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970082/my-css-gradient-doesnt-stretch-it-repeats/6970142#6970142) for more descriptive info about it.

Comment: this sort of worked. instead of repeating the gradient it just ends and leaves white for the rest of the page (http://imgur.com/a/6gfkB). Is there a way to expand the gradient to fit the entire web page for any levels of zoom?

Comment: @chefstu i will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Set html to height:100%; You can lose the 0% - 100% in the background css.

So (simplified without alt-browser options, for clarity):

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#10aaff,#2288aa); /* W3C */
}
```

Comment: Cool, glad that worked! Mind upvoting it/marking it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

For gradient to stretch the entire height of the page:

```
html {
    min-height: 100%
}
```

Additionally for no repeat of color on either of x axis or y axis ; that is; horizontally or vertically; use;

```
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```